# How to transform name of FXG file into SpriteVisualElement class?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have star.fxg file and i want create SpriteVisualElement class from String "star". 
I'm trying like this:

```
var classRef:Class = getDefinitionByName("star") as Class;
myStar = new ClassFactory(classRef).newInstance() as SpriteVisualElement;
```

but Flex say that *Variable star is not defined*.

But if i try:

```
myStar = new star() as SpriteVisualElement;
```

all working fine.

How to get instance of SpriteVisualElement from String name of fxg?

Comment: Use a fully classified path name.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com yes, it works, thanks!!! I write view.comps.star in getDefinitionByName and all have worked (^_^)

Comment: Great; I posted that as a formal answer.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Do you know, can I dont typing private var myStar1: star; if i need get instance of star class?

Comment: If you're asking if you can create a new instance of your FXG class directly; I believe the answer is yes.  I don't think you can do much with it in terms of visual display unless you wrap it in a Sprite or SpriteVisualElement, though.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com i ask about another thing. Your words about this problem: Importing it is only half the battle; the Flex compiler will remove that class if it isn't used explicitly. You also need a variable of that type. You do not have to instantiate it. Or you could force the compilre not to remove the class w/ a Compiler argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use the fully qualified class name. Instead of `star` use `com.myPackage.mySubPackage.star`